# Selecting Children without ID or Class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select a input textbox from within 2 parent divs with classes and/or ids. There are so many examples and methods of doing this that I have tried so many that I have resorted to posting this question for assistance in the event that someone else may encounter this issue.

### CODE

```
<div class="tblsearch">
    <div id="ElementCount10_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
        <label>
            Search:
            <input type="text">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="ElementCount10_info" class="dataTables_info"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
$(this).parent(".dataTables_filter").children("label").children("input").click(function () { alert('we got here'); });

$(".tblsearch.dataTables_filter label > input").click(function () {
    alert('hovered');
});

$(this).parent(".dataTables_filter").children("input").click(function () { alert('we got here'); });
```

I have been unable to access the selector.  I need to check if someone clicks into the box and fire off a function. This seems super easy and I must be missing something in my syntax.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: just curious - what's your reason of not adding an ID to the input? is it to make it generic?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What click event do you want to handle? Do you want to bind dynamically or on page load?

Comment: It is dynamically created using the jquery datatables plugin and can generate multiple datatables. That is why we can not have an id.

Comment: @koala_dev: I am only trying access the click event to see if/when anyone clicks into the textbox. I can handle that once I have accessed the selector properly and return an alert as a test. Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4urQc/)**

```
$('.dataTables_filter').on('click', 'input', function() {
    alert('here we are!');
});
```

Try this. If you need it more specific, you can do `input[type="text"]` or something.

This uses event delegation (see @Methletics's link for more information). So, this would handle any clicks on any `input`s within the parent.

Comment: Thanks kalley!  This worked perfect!  So you have identified the parent and then search directly for the field using the built-in jquery handlers?

Comment: @HeatherRoberts this binds the click handler to the parent and listens for clicks from the children. [Read about event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/)

Comment: @Mathletics is correct. I updated my answer to be a little more explanatory about what exactly is happening. But I'll leave the full discussion on event delegation to the link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the second selector is that you didn't have a space between the class names, including a space will make it work like expected - as the `<div>` with class `.tblsearch` is an *ancestor* of the `<div>` with class `.dataTables_filter`

```
$(".tblsearch .dataTables_filter label > input")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MxffP/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [[DEMO]](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/vZBzx/).

```
$(".dataTables_filter").children("label").children("input").click(function () { alert('we got here'); });

$(".dataTables_filter label > input").click(function () {
    alert('hovered');
});

$(".dataTables_filter").find("input").click(function () { alert('we got here'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

`children` only searches one level down. To search multiple levels down, use `find` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vs5zZ/2/